# Docker on Windows using Hyper-V. How to dynamically added space to docker or extend to harddrive when heavy Images pulled

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, hyper-v, boot2docker, docker-for-windows

Heavy Images are pulled, exceeds the 59gb of space on /dev/sda1.

How do I increase this? When I enable dynamic memory on the vm through Hyper-V every time docker is run is resets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hyper-V Manager, go to MobyLinuxVM Settings => SCSI Controller => Hard Drive. Choose edit and follow the wizard, it will allow you to expand disk space.